# Lost connection to "iPad 2"

Tags: ipad, xcode6

I have stopped all simulator processes but still getting below error.

Restore the connection to "iPad 2" and run "APPNAME" again, or if "APPNAME" is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > APPNAME.

Getting this error in Xcode 6,which is not consistent,but need to build it once again.

Please drop reasons if someone knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you have 2 projects open in XCode you want to debug at same time.

To **reproduce** the problem:

1. Launch a program in debug on the i(whatever) device
2. Go to another (dependency) project and select Debug -> attach to process -> process launched at 1.

To **avoid** the problem:

1. Launch the main process straight from the device
2. Go to the dependency project and select Debug -> attach to process -> process launched at 1.

Comment: For me it happened just running the same project simultaneously on two devices

Comment: What does `dependency project` mean?!

Comment: The dependency project is the xcode project of a library/framework you want to debug (used by a running App)