# Lost connection to iPad

Tags: ios, iphone

When I run my iOS application in the iPad for the first time in Xcode 6.0.1, I get this error message:

> Lost connection to "iPad 2".  Restore the connection to "iPad 2" and run "App Name” again, or if "App Name" is still > > running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > App Name.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lost connection to "iPad 2"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334178/lost-connection-to-ipad-2)

Comment: @ViralSavaj There are lot of questions on stack overflow are duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

This happens when you have 2 projects open in XCode you want to debug at same time.

**To reproduce the problem:**

Launch a program in debug on the i(whatever)(iPad or iPhone) device    .

Go to another (dependency) project and select Debug -> attach to process -> process launched at 1.

**To avoid the problem:**

Launch the main process straight from the device
Go to the dependency project and select Debug -> attach to process -> process launched at 1.

Same problem is addressed here with the same answer.
[Lost connection to “iPad 2”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334178/lost-connection-to-ipad-2#26487325)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334178/lost-connection-to-ipad-2#26487325